# JNI - Who frees ByteBuffer returned by a Java method?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I understand when a call is made from Java to C, there is no need to release memory obtained by `GetDirectBufferAddress`method. The garbage collector knows when to reclaim the memory. In my case, I am calling a Java method from C. Here is a code snippet for my Java method:

```
ByteBuffer processTask() {
   ...
   ByteBuffer retVal = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(len);
   return retVal;
}
```

Here is a code snippet from my C function:

```
jobject retVal = invokeProcessTask();
uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(retVal);
```

In this case, I am thinking the garbage collector has no idea when to collect the `ByteBuffer`instance. I am thinking it will be my C code's responsibility to release this memory. Is this right? If so, what function do I need to call to release it? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNI docs do not seem to make this clear.  They do say that all Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references, and I see no reason to doubt that that applies whether or not the JNI function is called inside the scope of a broader native method invocation.  The VM is responsible for keeping track of objects passed to native code, so as not to GC them while still in use, and I think it's necessary to interpret "passed" as including "returned to".

I am therefore inclined to agree with the interpretation that when a Java VM is embedded in a C program, and the program obtains a reference to a Java object by calling a JNI function outside the scope of a Java -> C native method invocation, that the referred-to object and all those reachable from it remain ineligible for GC until the C program explicitly releases its reference (at least).  The program can release local references via the `DeleteLocalRef()` function.

Note, too, JNI provides for only a limited number of local references to live in the same JNI environment at any given time.  That number can be managed via `EnsureLocalCapacity()`, `PushLocalFrame()`, and `PopLocalFrame()`, but you must take care to avoid exceeding it, which may be more of a risk in the embedding scenario you describe than it is in a short-running, narrow-scoped native method invocation.

Comment: I can't agree that it isn't clear. If no qualification is made, the statement applies unconditionally.

Comment: @EJP, For the most part, the JNI docs simply are not addressed to the embedding case.  For example, they say "Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call. They are freed automatically after the native method returns," but they say nothing about local references obtained outside the scope of any native method call.  The answer to the OP's question is therefore not clear from those docs; in many respects, one is obligated to infer and extrapolate from the native method case to the embedding case.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Looks like my best bet is not to obtain a Java object from C side. I changed my code such that I call my Java method from C and this Java method in turn calls a different C method, passing in the parameter I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `DeleteLocalRef()`, but there's probably no need unless the C method is really long-running: GC can collect it any time after the JNI method returns.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Remember that I am calling from C into Java. If GC will collect anytime after the JNI method returns, I may potentially be using a dangling pointer.